# Space complexity analysis of a function for traversing a linked list in reverse?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, space-complexity

Given a node with the following struct:

```
typedef struct listElementStruct{
  void* data;
  size_t size; //size of data not list
  struct listElementStruct* next;
  void (*print_func)(void*); //pointer to one of the custom print functions
} listElement;
```

Does this function have a constant memory O(1) or linear O(n) space complexity?

```
void reverse_traverse(listElement* start){

  listElement* current = start;
  int size_of_list=0;

  while(current != NULL){
      current=current->next;
      size_of_list++;
  }

  int nextVisit = size_of_list;

  While(nextVisit>=0){
     current = start;
     for(int i=0;i<nextVisit;i++){
         current = current->next;
     } 
     current->print_func(current->data);
     nextVisit--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Comment: If the space complexity is not O(1) but rather O(N), how would you explain/prove that? Where is the function allocating memory in proportion to the size of the list? Which statements/expressions in the function allocate memory, using what discipline?

Comment: Worth mentioning is the above function was created by me. The assignment was to comment about the memory required to traverse a linked list (which we needed to create in C) in reverse. I created several functions but a friend keeps insisting the above uses O(n) so I want a more experienced opinion.

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa Has your friend justified his claim? What is his justification?

Comment: "Space complexity" requires a definition to answer your question. Mostly people are interested in space taken by the algorithm exclusive of inputs and outputs. Real programs use stack frame and heap memory. Your algorithm uses a few local variables in one stack frame (no recursion) and no heap (`malloc()`) . With these observations you should be able to answer your own question. Your friend might be reasoning that an input list of size n requires O(n) space. That's not a normal way to analyze algorithm memory use.